# Оптимальный алгоритм на графах

Tags: графы

На графе существует две особые вершины: синяя и красная. Задача состоит в том, чтобы при удалении красной вершины, также удалить все вершины из которых нельзя достичь синей, т.е. граф как бы должен распасться на два, один из которых подлежит удалению.

Мое решение состоит в том, чтобы проверить существование пути из каждой вершины в синюю. Если все пути очередной вершины проходят через красную, то производить удаление этой вершины.

Может существует более оптимальное решение?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А если так:

1. Удалить красную вершину и все ребра, примыкающие к ней.
2. В получившемся графе провести поиск в глубину из синей вершины.

Найденная компонента связности и есть искомый результат.